# Read data in Amazon Sagemaker from an Amazon S3 bucket with different credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm a beginner to Amazon Sagemaker. My organization has Amazon Sagemaker and some Amazon S3 buckets which I can access with a given key and secret key (say account A). One of our providers has given us read-access to some data in one of their own Amazon S3 buckets using a different key and secret key (say account B). I have verified that I have read-access to the data using boto3 in a jupyter notebook with the keys they provided.

The application is training a CNN using Tensorflow, the data are images (annotations have been provided separately in the form of json files and are not in the bucket). I am aware Amazon Sagemaker has some functionality with Tensorflow but I have never used them. I would like to understand if I can benefit from them in my use case.

Questions:

1. While using Amazon Sagemaker in account A, can I (in general) read data from an Amazon S3 bucket in account B without having to copy it locally?
2. Can I take advantage of Amazon Sagemaker's integration with Tensorflow in my specific use case or is that only useful for buckets in the same account as Amazon Sagemaker?
3. From the perspective of training the model: Would it make any difference/would it be advisable to duplicate the data by copying the images to an Amazon S3 bucket in account A? There are over 10k high-resolution pictures.

Answer (score 0):

1. While using Amazon Sagemaker in account A, can I (in general) read data from an Amazon S3 bucket in account B without having to copy it locally?
   Yes you need to enable cross account permission for you bucket and add a policy to your role in sagemaker to access it. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/
2. Can I take advantage of Amazon Sagemaker's integration with Tensorflow in my specific use case or is that only useful for buckets in the same account as Amazon Sagemaker?
   not relevant, see answer to previous question
3. From the perspective of training the model: Would it make any difference/would it be advisable to duplicate the data by copying the images to an Amazon S3 bucket in account A? There are over 10k high-resolution pictures.
   there should be no need to do that, refer to question 1. sagemaker would pull your data from any bucket as long as it has permission to it. some latency might be introduced depending if the buckets and the job are being called from different regions.